# Displaying ACF Group Data Outside WordPress Loop

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to display the below code outside wordpress loop using ajax tabs.

My Tabs are like this

```
<!-- Tab links -->
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li><a href="<?php
    echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
?>/includes/tabs/specs.php" class="tab">Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab_2">Overview</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I want to display the below code inside my tab "data". But it's not working. This code working perfectly on other pages inside a loop.

```
 <?php
 $group_ID = 12113;
 $fields = get_fields($groupID);

 $fields = get_field_objects();
echo '<div class="aps-column">';
echo '<div class="aps-group">';
echo '<ul class="aps-specs-list">';

          if( $fields )
          {
            foreach( $fields as $field_name => $field )
            {
              if( $field['value'] )
              {
                  echo ' <li>';
                    echo '<strong class="aps-term">' . $field['label'] . '</strong>';
echo '<div class="aps-attr-value"><span class="aps-1co">' . $field['value'] . '</span></div>';
echo '</li>';
                }
            }
          }
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: Is there any reason for declaring the variable $fields twice above?

Comment: Hi @AndrewM I don't know the exact code. I copied it from somewhere else.